# Error Adding react-pdf to SPFx web part

Tags: spfx, react, pdf

I'm trying to add react-pdf to my webpart, but I'm getting the error `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file`. Most answers I found pointed me to installing `@babel/preset-env`, so I create a `.babelrc` file with the presets, and add the following to the gulp config file:

```
build.rig.addPreBuildTask((gulp) => {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.tsx'])
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});
```

This gives a `Found non-callable @@iterator` and I found no solution for this.Tried installing the `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugin, and it didn't work either.

`@mikecousins/react-pdf` gives me the same error.

How can I add the appropriate loader so I can show PDF files on screen on my React web part?